# Click on the screen co-ordinate in ios

Tags: ios, touch, programmatically-created

I want to create a fake touch in iOS ViewController programmatically by giving the co-ordinates as input it should work like a manual touch please guide me in achieving that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be possible, Once I found something that does the same as you wanted. But I would like you to read these line that the author wrote a the beginning of that post:

The content of this post is **for debugging and testing only**. Do not submit this code in an application to the App Store. Doing so will likely result in:

1. A bad UI experience for your users.
2. An app that breaks on every OS update.
3. Rejection of your application.

Here is the [link](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine that you need such a function for testing the user interface. If this is the case, you should consider using [Xcode's Automation instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html) (Product -> Profile).
This instrument allows you e.g. to simulate touches to interface elements like buttons.
You could execute instructions like

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().navigationBar().buttons()["Add"].tap();
```